# Trying to add another child inside body: center

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to add another child for photo view inside the body: center, but its causing some error. Here's my code snippet -

```
body: Center(
    child: _image == null ()
        ? Text('No image selected.')
        : Image.file(_image),
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Column Widget or Row widget to get more widgets together.

```
Center(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      _image == null
      ? Text('No image selected.')
      : Image.file(_image),
      AssetImage(
        'assets/images/image.png',
      ),
  ],
),
```

[documentation on Columns](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html)

Comment: Once I have run that, it gives me this error:
The method 'call' isn't defined for the class 'Null'.

Comment: I missed the ternary mistake. Delete the () after the word null.

Answer (score 0):

Look like the ternary statement is wrong -

**Try this -**

```
  body: Center(
    child: _image == null ? Text('No image selected.') : Image.file(_image),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body: Center(
    child: _image == null
        ? Text('No image selected.')
        : Image.file(_image),
),
```

This should work. Why did you use () after _image == null??